# unable to use pip to install packages pkg_ressources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and pip seems to be broken now. I am unable to install any package with it and even running commands such as pip -version or pip install -U pip, give me the same error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Is there a solution for this bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I made pip work again like this. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
sudo rm /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

but then I was getting an error message saying `usr/local/bin/pip not found` so I created a symbolic link from `/usr/local/bin/pip` to `/usr/bin/pip` using:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
```

and now pip works.

Answer (score 0):

in  my case, I got this error because pip packages were installed multiple times

I fixed this error fixed by removing `rm /usr/local/bin/pip`
As `pip` was also found in `~/.local/bin/`